# Set default location to save file with python

Tags: python

I'm creating a python script to convert all files in a folder into another format informed by the user, but I wanted to ask only once for the location to save the files. I already tried to use askdirectory () but it gives a strange error that the directory where the files are being the same from where they will be saved even adding different variables.

```
import glob
import img2pdf
from pathlib import Path
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory


def img_to_pdf(arq, savefile):
    with open(f"{str(arq)[0:-4]}.pdf", "wb") as f:
        f.write(img2pdf.convert(arq))


def convert(filelocal, inpt, outpt, savefile):
    path = Path(str(filelocal))
    for arq in path.glob('*'):
        if arq.endswith(str(inpt)):
            if inpt == ".png" and outpt == ".pdf":
                img_to_pdf(arq, savefile)


def localfile():
    Tk().withdraw()
    filelocal = askdirectory()
    return filelocal


def filesave():
    Tk().withdraw()
    savefile = askdirectory()
    return savefile


if __name__ == '__main__':
    inpt = ".png"
    outpt = ".pdf"
    filelocal = localfile()
    savefile = filesave()
    convert(filelocal, inpt, outpt, savefile)
```

Any suggestions on how I can solve this problem? Because the solutions I found so far only help if it is to save a single file, so for each file in the folder, it would ask for the location again. What I want is to define a location to save as a default.

Comment: Please provide the actual error

Comment: From the looks of things, `f.write(img2pdf.convert(arq))` isn't even considering your `savefile` location. You should specify the target location in your `with open(...)`. If you just want to copy a file I suggest you look into shutil: https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html

Comment: If `img_to_pdf` should use the selected directory it would be a good idea to use this directory. You don't use `outpt` anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I think I was not very clear with the sample code, but i already solve the problem. If someone has the same question, the way I did it was, instead of going one by one the files to convert, the function receives a list with the path of all of them and the askdirectory() function I open in the function that will convert, then I do a for loop to convert file by file and move to the destination folder.

like this:

```
def img_to_pdf(arq):
    save_file = str(askdirectory(initialdir="/home"))
    for i in arq:
        fullname = str(i)[0:-4] + '.pdf'
        with open(fullname,"wb") as f:
            f.write(img2pdf.convert(str(i)))
        shutil.move(fullname, save_file)
```